# Using PHP to call Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, php

Whats wrong with this code?  It doesn't do anything.

As of now the `$_GET` works well and receives all return values from server side.  All data is available: $_GET['PNREF']; & $_GET['EMAIL']; receive data fine when I have them outside of the if statement.

```
<?php

if($_GET['RESPMSG'] != "Approved"){

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
    'declined();',
    '</script>';

}else{

    echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
    'approved();',
    '</script>';

    $tranid  = $_GET['PNREF'];
    $email   = $_GET['EMAIL'];
}

?>
```

I'm trying to access these two functions located in the `<body>`

```
<script>

function approved(){
   alert("approved func");
   document.getElementById('oops_id').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('thank_id').style.display = "block";

}
function declined(){
   alert("declined func");
   document.getElementById('thank_id').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('oops_id').style.display = "block";
}

</script>
```

Comment: How are the two JS functions included in the page?

Comment: Just have them between <script> tags in the body.

Comment: What body? That's not shown in your question. Where on the page does the PHP if/else output the calls to the functions? That would need to be after the functions themselves.

Comment: Nothing visible in the debug console? Does any of the code actually show up in the source in the browser? You provide too little context to even tell if this is a mere syntax error in PHP or something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's your final html (generated by PHP) looks like ?

I guess that you declaration of php if is among the top and javascript method declaration is way below, by the time method is call it not yet declared

then you have 2 choices

1. Move approved() and declined() to the top, before your php if
2. Do it more properly using [document ready of jquery](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)

---

Or try this

```
<?php

echo '<script type="text/javascript">var resp =' + $_GET['RESPMSG'] + '</script>';
if($_GET['RESPMSG'] == "Approved"){
    $tranid  = $_GET['PNREF'];
    $email   = $_GET['EMAIL'];
}

?>
```

---

```
function approved(){
   alert("approved func");
   document.getElementById('oops_id').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('thank_id').style.display = "block";

}
function declined(){
   alert("declined func");
   document.getElementById('thank_id').style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById('oops_id').style.display = "block";
}
if(resp == "Approved") { approved(); } else { declined(); }
```

Comment: So my code looks ok? No errors?  Only placement you think

Comment: looks like it would work, just only code placement, yes.

Comment: ps. my edit add more example

Comment: Your completely right, it was all about placement.  A simple solution.  I don't know why some of these answers are complicated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't expect any action from your script.

PHP is executed on your server, while Javascript is executed on the Client.

In your PHP `if` statement, you are only *including* the function call to be executed sometime while the page is loading (asyncronously).

You need to call the `declined()` or `approved()` function in a JavaScript script, based upon some user interaction.

I would need to see more code to make more recommendations than this.

Comment: This form does receive data successfully from $_GET - I have tested.  And I know for sure $_GET['PNREF']; & $_GET['EMAIL']; receive values.  So I was hoping my problem was just in a bad if statement.

Comment: Yes, but you need a JavaScript script to call the functions.  You currently have PHP only include the function call.  For example, you may choose a button to have an `on_click` event which THEN calls the appropriate function.  This would only occur on the client (within the web browser).  Nothing would be sent back to PHP to process.  Please review the client server model: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model

Comment: Updated question

Answer (score 0):

You may want to rethink how you approach this: one way to do it is to mark the element's style as "display: none" or "display: block" directly based on the request variable.

```
<?php
    $declined = $_GET['RESPMSG'] != 'Approved';
?>
```

Then in the html:

```
<div id="thank_id" style="display: <?php echo $declined ? "none" : "block"; ?>;">
    <!-- thank div contents here -->
</div>
<div id="oop_id" style="display: <?php echo $declined ? "block" : "none"; ?>;">
    <!-- oop div contents here -->
</div>
```

If you really want to have your javascript functions run, you may be able to have the page run your function when the body loads using the php portion above to determine which function to run:

```
<body onLoad="<?php echo $declined ? "declined();" : "accepted();"; ?>">
```

Comment: Thanks @Cubis I will try to simplify what I have with your suggestion.